# How to receive POST array params in ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

can`t receive post body array params

```
$.post(
  'http://some_url/url',
  {
    order_items: [
      {
        order_item_id: 1,
        action_id: 1,
        fulfillment_time: "String 1"
      },
      {
        order_item_id: 2,
        action_id: 2,
        fulfillment_time: "string 2"}
    ]
  }
);
```

```
post("/url") {
    val params = call.receiveParameters()
}
```

i got array/map:

```
order_items[0][order_item_id]=[1],
order_items[0][action_id]=[1],
order_items[0][fulfillment_time]=[1s],
order_items[1][order_item_id]=[2],
order_items[1][action_id]=[2],
order_items[1][fulfillment_time]=[2s]
```

and i cant get param `order_items`.

```
val p1 = params.get("order_items") //null
val p2 = params.get("order_items[0][order_item_id]") //1
```

Comment: Can you show us your ktor set up? I think `params` is a map, and does not work like json.

Comment: I believe you are missing something here, maybe parsing. are you using some Moshi or Gson to parse that JSON ?\

Answer (score 0):

You could use `call.receiveParameters().getAll("array[]")`.

Where `<input name="array[]">`.

But I suggest to use breakpoints, and try debugging, how actually Ktor parses your payload.